# How to append element if checkbox is checked and remove it if unchecked?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of order and if element is selected (checked) - it sums the value and shows the text of element that is selected. How to show text of selected elements and remove it when unchecked? 
[Link to code pen](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/xVxgYM).

And the js itself:

```
$(".price-of-package-element").change(function () {
    var count = 0,
        priceElement = $(".price-of-package-element");   
  for (var i = 0; priceElement[i]; ++i) {
        if (priceElement[i].checked) {
            var value = priceElement[i].value,
                title = $(this).next().text();
            count += Number(priceElement[i].value);
            $('#text').append("<div>" + title + "</div>");

        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: Look at my edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code given by @VivekPipaliya replace all the previously texts by the last appended.

The following code will works :

```
$(".price-of-package-element").change(function () {
  var count = 0,
  priceElement = $(".price-of-package-element");   
  for (var i = 0; priceElement[i]; ++i) {
        if (priceElement[i].checked) {
            var value = priceElement[i].value,
                title = $(this).next().text();
            count += Number(priceElement[i].value);
        }
    } 
    $('#text').append("<div>" + title + "</div>"); // Append the div from out of the loop
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/chalasr/pen/ONJpaE)

**Update**

I finally got it:

```
$(".price-of-package-element").change(function () {
    var priceElement = $(this);
    var id = priceElement.attr('id');
    var title = $(this).next().text();
    var textId = 'text-' + id;

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#text').append("<div id='"+ textId +"'>" + title + "</div>"); // Append the div from out of the loop
    } else {
        $('#'+textId).remove();
    }
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chalasr/pen/ONJpaE)

Comment: Run your code in http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/xVxgYM
& then post the answer X-(

Comment: Yes, thanks I will add it.  but yours squash appended elements by replace their text by the last given.

Comment: @NeedHate please re-try :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `$('#text').html('');` before append new one because you appending all div again when new checkbox is checked.

Use following code.

```
$(".price-of-package-element").change(function () {
  var count = 0,
  priceElement = $(".price-of-package-element");   
  $('#text').html('');
  for (var i = 0; priceElement[i]; ++i) {
        if (priceElement[i].checked) {
            var value = priceElement[i].value,
                title = $(this).next().text();
            count += Number(priceElement[i].value);
            $('#text').append("<div>" + title + "</div>");

        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: Yeah. it removes appended... but see the result if any other tab is select (to the left).